# Hide local tabs in specific content type

Tags: 7

I want to hide the local tabs for a specific content type. How can I do this? I don't want to complete remove it since I want to show them in other content types

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) ? If you're using D7 a [port](http://drupal.org/node/1007226#comment-4895340) in on its way.

Comment: yes I have used tab tamer but that hides from all pages and I only want to hide on certain content types